# Rails 4: CanCanCan abilities with has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan, cancancan

I have a Rails app with the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

For a given `calendar`, a `user` has a `role`, which is define in the `administration` join model.

For each calendar, a user can have only one of the following three roles: `Owner`, `Editor` or `Viewer`.

These roles are currently not stored in dictionary or a constant, and are only assigned to an administration as strings ("Ower", "Editor", "Viewer") through different methods.

Authentication on the `User` model is handled through Devise, and the `current_user` method is working.

In order to only allow logged-in users to access in-app resources, I have already add the `before_action :authenticate_user!` method in the `calendars` and `administrations` controllers.

Now, I need to implement a role-based authorization system, so I just installed the `CanCanCan` gem.

Here is what I want to achieve:

- All (logged-in) `user`s can create new `calendar`s.
- If a `user` is the `owner` of a `calendar`, then he can `manage` the `calendar` and all the `administration`s that belong to this `calendar`, including his own `administration`.
- If a user is `editor` of a `calendar`, then he can `read` and `update` this calendar, and destroy his `administration`.
- If a `user` is `viewer` of a `calendar`, then he can `read` this `calendar`, and `destroy` his `administration`.

To implement the above, I have come up with the following `ability.rb` file:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user, calendar)
    user ||= User.new
    calendar = Calendar.find(params[:id])
    user can :create, :calendar
    if user.role?(:owner)
      can :manage, :calendar, :user_id => user.id
      can :manage, :administration, :user_id => user.id
      can :manage, :administration, :calendar_id => calendar.id
    elsif user.role?(:editor)
      can [:read, :update], :calendar, :user_id => user.id
      can :destroy, :administration, :user_id => user.id
    elsif user.role?(:viewer)
      can [:read], :calendar, :user_id => user.id
      can :destroy, :administration, :user_id => user.id
    end    
  end
end
```

Since I am not very experimented with Rails and it is the first time I am working with `CanCanCan`, I am not very confident with my code and would like some validation or advice for improvement.

So, would this code work, and would it allow me to achieve what I need?

**UPDATE**: with the current code, when I log in as a user, and visit the calendars#show page of another user's calendar, I can actually access the calendar, which I should not.

So, obviously, my code is not working.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE 2**: I figured there were errors in my code, since I was using `:model` instead of `Model` to allow `user`s to perform actions on a given `model`.

However, the code is still not working.

Any idea of what could be wrong here?

**UPDATE 3**: could the issue be caused by the fact that I use `if user.role?(:owner)` to check if a user's role is set to owner, while in the database the role is actually defined as "Owner" (as a string)?

UPDATE 4: I kept on doing some research and I realized I had done two mistakes.

1. I had not added `load_and_authorize_resource` to the `calendars` and `administrations` controllers.
2. I had defined two attributes two parameters — `initialize(user, calendar)` — instead of one in my `initialize` method.

So, updated both controllers, as well as the ability.rb file as follows:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.role?(:owner)
      can :manage, Calendar, :user_id => user.id
      can :manage, Administration, :user_id => user.id
      can :manage, Administration, :calendar_id => calendar.id
    elsif user.role?(:editor)
      can [:read, :update], Calendar, :user_id => user.id
      can :destroy, Administration, :user_id => user.id
    elsif user.role?(:viewer)
      can [:read], Calendar, :user_id => user.id
      can :destroy, Administration, :user_id => user.id
    end    
  end
end
```

Now, when I try to visit a calendar that does not belong to the `current_user`, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in CalendarsController#show
undefined method `role?' for #<User:0x007fd003dff860>
def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.role?(:owner)
      can :manage, Calendar, :user_id => user.id
      can :manage, Administration, :user_id => user.id
      can :manage, Administration, :calendar_id => calendar.id
```

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method `role?` the User model. The Cancancan documentation is at fault for assuming such a method exists in the examples.

To fix this, you should instead do:

```
if user.role == 'Owner'
  ...
elsif user.role == 'Editor'
  ...
elsif user.role == 'Viewer'
  ...
```

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks!